# Why isn't unittest test case run

Tags: python

I have the following `unittest` test case:

```
import unittest
from ElementExtractor import ElementExtractor

class ElementExtractorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def allListsHaveSameSize(self):
        self.assertTrue(1 == 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am running it from the command line `python ElementExtractorTest.py` and I get this output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why is the unit test not run?
How can I make it run?

Comment: Because you don't have a valid test method in your class. Test methods start with the name `test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import unittest
from ElementExtractor import ElementExtractor

class ElementExtractorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_allListsHaveSameSize(self): #add test here to be picked up
        self.assertTrue(1 == 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Isn't this just the code from the question with an altered function name? You should include an explanation for your answer. How did you solve it, why is your code different, and so on.